# How to retrieve values from a parameter of type object

Tags: c#, object, parameters

I have a method that receives parameters when it is called.

```
public void OnFocusChanged(object parameter)
{            
}
```

The parameters are placed within an `object` because the method is called in the following way (the part where `else if (Converter != null)`):

```
void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
{
        if (Command == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        object resolvedParameter;

        if (CommandParameter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
        }
        else if (Converter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = Converter.Convert(eventArgs, typeof(object), AssociatedObject, null);
        }
        else
        {
            resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
        }

        if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
        }
}
```

Actually I want to pass `sender` and `eventArgs` from `OnEvent` to `OnFocusChanged`, which actually functions, but I cannot extract the relevant information.

So I modified the `OnEvent` method as follows:

```
void OnEvent(object sender, object eventArgs)
{
        if (Command == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        object resolvedParameter;

        if (CommandParameter != null)
        {
            resolvedParameter = CommandParameter;
        }
        else if (Converter != null)
        {
            var senderItem = (Syncfusion.SfNumericTextBox.XForms.SfNumericTextBox)sender;

            var propertyInfoID = senderItem.BindingContext.GetType().GetProperty("ID");
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfoID.GetValue(senderItem.BindingContext));

            var propertyInfoGroupID = senderItem.BindingContext.GetType().GetProperty("GroupID");
            int groupID = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfoGroupID.GetValue(senderItem.BindingContext));

            resolvedParameter = (id, groupID);
        }
        else
        {
            resolvedParameter = eventArgs;
        }

        if (Command.CanExecute(resolvedParameter))
        {
            Command.Execute(resolvedParameter);
        }
}
```

But now there is the same problem in the `OnFocusChanged` method.

I see the parameters, but cannot extract them.

[Screenshot where the parameters can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPSui.png)

My questions are:

- How can I extract the parameters from the object, because I cannot access them with Item1 or Item2?
- Where is documentation for that?
- Where is documentation for

```
var propertyInfoGroupID = senderItem.BindingContext.GetType().GetProperty("GroupID");
int groupID = Convert.ToInt32(propertyInfoGroupID.GetValue(senderItem.BindingContext));
```

Because that's what I found while searching...

It is working, but how can I access different information from base classes in future?

Comment: Cast to ValueTuple<int, int> ? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple